# looping through array - only first index printing

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I want to loop through an array and print any values that are not null, here is the code I am trying to use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (studentNamesArray[i] != null) {
    studentFound = true;
    System.out.println("Which student would you like to delete?");
    System.out.println(i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
    int studentChoice = input.nextInt();
  }
}
```

Array:

`static String[] studentNamesArray = new String[10];`

The problem is that it is only printing out `index[0]`. How can I fix this?

EDIT:

Here is my full code:

```
  static void deleteStudent() {
    boolean studentFound = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      if (studentNamesArray[i] != null) {
        studentFound = true;
        System.out.println("Which student would you like to delete?");
        System.out.println(i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
      }
        int studentChoice = input.nextInt();
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (i = studentChoice + 1; i < studentNamesArray.length; i++) {
          studentNamesArray[i - 1] = studentNamesArray[i];
        }
        nameArrayCount = nameArrayCount - 1;
        studentNamesArray[studentNamesArray.length - 1] = null;
        for (i = studentChoice + 1; i < 9; i++) {
          for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            studentMarksArray[i - 1][y] = studentMarksArray[i][y];
          }
        }
        markArrayCount = markArrayCount - 1;
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
          studentMarksArray[9][y] = 0;
        }
      }
    }
    if (!studentFound) {
      System.out.println("There are no students stored");
    }
  }
```

Comment: From this code, the output will never be `index[0]`

Comment: Will you ask the question `Which student would you like to delete?` 10 times? Why?

Comment: @AycanYaşıt He ask only the times studentNames is not null.

Comment: Are you sure that your program has exited that loop? Or is it waiting for input?

Comment: show us the code where you initialize the elements of studentNamesArray[]. Anyways, why do you need the local variable studentChoice? You can't use it since it's scopes ends with the if statement...

Comment: It's waiting for input @PakkuDon. it prompts the user for input, I've another method to print the array elements if they are not null and it is returning all the elements that the user inputs so I know the element exists

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the for-loop only to print the students names. And read the `studentChoice` once after you printed all the students. Otherwise it waits for input after printing the `studentNamesArray[0]`

```
System.out.println("Which student would you like to delete?");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  if (studentNamesArray[i] != null) {
    studentFound = true;
    System.out.println(i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
  }
}
int studentChoice = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: In the code you posted the line: int studentChoice = input.nextInt(); is still in the for-loop. You only put it out of the if condition.

Comment: ahh sorry I must have missed a bracket! It seems to be working as expected now

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the contents of the array are not null, or they wont print out

Comment: I've entered ten elements but only the first is printing

Comment: are the elements really entered, try taking the `if (studentNamesArray[i] != null) {...}` away and see what prints out

Comment: With that line removed only the first element is still printed

Comment: Then I can only imagine that it's stopping it the end of the first loop waiting for input.

Comment: if this isn't true then we'll need to see more code to debug the problem

Comment: I've added the rest of my code, I tried moving the input to outside the for loop but the same thing is happening

Answer (score 1):

Only reason I can see here, other elements should be `null`. You can make sure it as follows

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   if (studentNamesArray[i] != null) {
      studentFound = true;
      System.out.println("Which student would you like to delete?");
      System.out.println(i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
      int studentChoice = input.nextInt();// you need to check this 
     }else{
      System.out.println(i + ": " + studentNamesArray[i]);
     }
   }
```

**But** may be there is another reason. If `input.nextInt()` is take from `Scanner`, your program will wait there for a user input. Then you have to provide that input to continue. Make sure those things.

Comment: I've added the rest of my code, I tried moving the input to outside the for loop but the same thing is happening